# Parsing xml file with for each

Tags: xml, vb.net

I need to add rows to datatable for each of these values in xml:

```
<G_3>
 <UPP_ID>3381602200003739</UPP_ID>
</G_3>
    <LIST_G_1>
             <G_1>
              <BROJ>375383321</BROJ>
              <OPERR>11.07.18</OPERR>
              <KOME>22uzu</KOME>
              <TABTEXT>rbnrn</TABTEXT>
              <NAME>Ban</NAME>
              <TASK>6000</TASK>
              <B_TASK>0</B_TASK>
              <FLAG>1</FLAG>
              <ELGE_A>1</ELGE_A>
              <ELGE_B>12000</ELGE_B>
              <ELGE_C>0</ELGE_C>
              <ELGE_D>-134675.56</ELGE_D>
              <ELGE_0>338250220001727</ELGE_0>
            </G_1>
            <G_1>
              <BROJ>375383568</BROJ>
              <OPERR>11.07.18</OPERR>
              <KOME>3383202200001622</KOME>
              <TABTEXT> PL. RN.</TABTEXT>
              <NAME>ban43</NAME>
              <TASK>6000</TASK>
              <B_TASK>0</B_TASK>
              <FLAG>1</FLAG>
              <ELGE_A>1</ELGE_A>
              <ELGE_B>18000</ELGE_B>
              <ELGE_C>0</ELGE_C>
              <ELGE_D>-140675.56</ELGE_D>
              <ELGE_0>3383202200001622</ELGE_0>
            </G_1>

</LIST_G_1>
```

How would i implement a for each loop to get values from this xml file.
This is part of the code which returns value from single node in this xml:

```
 Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
        doc.Load(textBox.Text)
        Dim UPP_IDi= doc.GetElementsByTagName("UPP_ID")
        For Each item As System.Xml.XmlElement In UPP_IDi
            UPP_ID.Text = item.InnerText
        Next
```

I want something like this in my console/listbox:

```
Broj:375383321
OPERR:11.07.18
KOME:22uzu
...
Broj:375383568
OPERR:11.07.18
KOME:3383202200001622
```

Comment: If the tags always have the same names it would be much easier and more efficient to use [**XML Serialization**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292726/Serialization-Part-III-XML-Serialization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication53
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement g_1 in doc.Descendants("G_1"))
            {
                string leader = "";

                foreach (XElement element in g_1.Elements())
                {
                    string output = string.Format("{0}{1}:{2}", leader, element.Name.LocalName, (string)element);
                    Console.WriteLine(output);

                    if (leader.Length == 0) leader = "     ";
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```